# Good use of property in classes

Tags: python-3.x

Can you explain my why this simple property is not working ??

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.person = listing
    def _set_listing(self):
        self._listing = {'a':'ok','b':'no','c':'yes'}
    listing = property(_set_listing)

i=Person()
```

Return the error
NameError: name 'listing' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listing` in `__init__` is an undefined local variable, not a reference to the `listing` property of `Person` objects. That would be `self.listing`.

You property has a getter that doesn't return anything, so it returns `None` implicitly, so `Person().listing` will be `None`.  I don't think that's what you want.

It looks like you're trying to define the setter method of the property, which would be like

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listing = 1
    def _set_listing(self, value):
        self._listing = {'a':'ok','b':'no','c':'yes', 'value': value}
    def _get_listing(self):
        return self._listing
    listing = property(_get_listing, _set_listing)

print(Person().listing['value'])  # 1
```

or (using the `property` decorator)

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listing = 1
    @property
    def listing(self):
        return self._listing
    @listing.setter
    def listing(self, value):
        self._listing = {'a':'ok','b':'no','c':'yes', 'value': value}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick it works fine, but how can I initialize with my dictionnary whitout being able to modifiy later on ?

Comment: Don't define a setter, and set `self._listing = value` in `__init__`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks !!